# SQL join giving duplicate rows with group by clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

Thanks for all help
i am  facing issue while using joins

Using one sccm query

```
    select count(distinct resourceid) as ModelCount,caption0,CSDVersion0 from [dbo].[v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM]  
where caption0 like '%Windows Server%'
group by caption0,CSDVersion0
```

Data iam getting is as following

[image]

so iam getting following data, and i have made a another table with extended support dates for every windows version

```
select * from datesinfo
```

data iam getting

[image]

after  doing join on both tables iam writing query this

```
    select count(distinct OS.resourceid) as ModelCount,(dt.serverinfo),CSDVersion0,dt.Extendedsupportenddate,dt.servicepacksupportenddate from [dbo].[v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM] OS
inner join datesinfo dt on  os.caption0=dt.serverinfo where os.caption0 like '%Windows Server%'
group by OS.caption0,OS.CSDVersion0,dt.serverinfo,dt.Extendedsupportenddate,dt.servicepacksupportenddate
```

iam getting one row duplicate with 672 rows, can you please explain why all data is distinct

[image]

Comment: this is the right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54787787/1633949

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `OS.caption0` which is not included in your `select` statement. 
I think that if you include this column then the 2 rows will not be duplicates.
Or maybe you don't want to group by this column so remove it from `group by`.

Comment: select count(distinct OS.resourceid) as ModelCount,os.caption0,CSDVersion0,dt.Extendedsupportenddate,dt.servicepacksupportenddate from [dbo].[v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM] OS
inner join datesinfo dt on  os.caption0=dt.serverinfo where os.caption0 like '%Windows Server%'
group by OS.caption0,OS.CSDVersion0,dt.Extendedsupportenddate,dt.servicepacksupportenddate still same i removed serverinfo and addedd caption0 still 14 rows. i dont understand why servicepack support date is different for SP2 it should be same

Comment: Why do you expect not to have 14 rows?

Comment: i expect  last row is duplicate it should not come, its increasing count giving false result in report.

Comment: It is not a duplicate

Comment: This answer isn't correct.  Adding another column to a SELECT clause will NEVER cause fewer rows to appear in the results.  Neither will removing a GROUP BY clause....it might well cause MORE rows.

Comment: @RichardII This answer provided something to test. And not selecting a column from group by can show duplicates that don't really exist

Comment: @forpas, your "answer" didn't describe itself as "something to test."  Stack Overflow answers should ANSWER the question, not guide the asker along toward self-discovery.    As expected, the OP just tried what you suggested, thinking it was the solution.     This would have been much better as a comment on the question.

Comment: @RichardII *I think that if you include this column then the 2 rows will not be duplicates* did you read this? What was this? Something to try. As for *Stack Overflow answers should ANSWER the question* most of the answers here on SO are based on a try basis especially when there is no actual data or the problem is not reproducable. So don't try to teach me how to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In datesinfo, you have record 3 and 5 that have the same name, with different servicepacksupportenddate.
Each appears once in your final result, this is normal.

Comment: but Service pack is different

Comment: You don't ask about the service pack in your query.
However, that would be one more reason to get 2 lines...

Comment: @deepti, so what?  what does service pack have to do with your final query?  it's not even mentioned.   this answer is correct.  you have multiple rows because one of your GROUP BY columns is the servicepacksupportenddate.  since that value is different on rows 3 and 5 in DatesInfo, you will get two rows.